# How to Change the label font size when selected from list of fonts for entire App in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to change the label font size throughout the App when selected from the list of fonts for Both Android and IOS in xamarin.forms. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

I can think about 3 different implementations how to do it:

1. Make FontConverter and attach to every label in app. Not elegant, time consuming.
2. Make behavior and attach to every label in app. This is better than first one.
3. Extend label and make ExtendedLabel, which would have listen to global event of changing font size. This would be cleanest
   implementation with best maintainability

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic styles to do this using `DynamicResource` rather than `StaticResource`. These respond to resource changes at run time like the font size being changed.

[There is a good guide here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/dynamic/)

[And a good blog post that walks you through how to do it here](https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/)